# Angular app in production slow to load due to file with 5 second load time

Tags: javascript, angular

I compiled my project for production:

```
ng build --prod
```

with the following production settings in angular.json:

```
        "production": {
          "fileReplacements": [
            {
              "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
              "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
            }
          ],
          "optimization": true,
          "outputHashing": "all",
          "sourceMap": false,
          "extractCss": true,
          "namedChunks": false,
          "aot": true,
          "extractLicenses": true,
          "vendorChunk": false,
          "buildOptimizer": true,
          "budgets": [
            {
              "type": "initial",
              "maximumWarning": "2mb",
              "maximumError": "5mb"
            },
            {
              "type": "anyComponentStyle",
              "maximumWarning": "6kb",
              "maximumError": "10kb"
            }
          ]
        }
```

Then I uploaded the project to S3. But when I load the page, it takes 5 seconds to load. I peruse Google Chrome Network tab and the following file has a content download of 5.4 seconds:

```
vendor-es2015.js
```

I assume this is the generated es5 compatible javascript file. But how can I reduce the download time of this? 5 seconds for the app to load is unbearable.

Comment: What are the sizes of the generated files

Comment: The issue was I was not replacing the old files on S3.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try fetching the file with postman ?

It doesn't seem to be an Angular issue but rather an issue due to a bad connexion or something related to S3 buckets maybe ?

Answer (score 0):

They way the libraries are imported in the project may affect the performance when using `ng --prod`

Are you using the format `@import "~<path>";` or the format `@import "../../<path>"` ?

Reference:
https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/6795#issuecomment-416236486

Comment: How is this issue going @Donato ?